# MySQL polymorphic join condition with OR not using index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, indexing, polymorphic-associations

I have tables `departments`, `employees`, and `emails` in MySQL 5.6.17 (for a Rails app). Each department has many employees, and both departments and employees have many emails. I want to sort `departments` by the number of emails to the entire department and individual employees within the department. My attempt:

```
SELECT departments.*, COUNT(DISTINCT employees.id) AS employees_count, COUNT(DISTINCT emails.id) AS emails_count
    FROM departments
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employees 
        ON employees.department_id = departments.id AND employees.is_employed = true
    LEFT OUTER JOIN emails 
        ON (emails.emailable_id = departments.id AND emails.emailable_type = 'department')
            OR (emails.emailable_id = employees.id AND emails.emailable_type = 'employee')
    GROUP BY departments.id 
    ORDER BY emails_count DESC 
    LIMIT 20;
```

Unfortunately, this query takes over 3 minutes to complete. Since this query will be used in a web interface, that's not a workable timeframe. An `EXPLAIN` gives:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys                                   | key                              | key_len | ref                           | rows  | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | departments | index | PRIMARY                                         | PRIMARY                          | 4       | NULL                          | 37468 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees   | ref   | index_employees_on_department_id                | index_employees_on_department_id | 5       | development_db.departments.id |     5 | Using where                                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | emails      | ALL   | index_emails_on_emailable_id_and_emailable_type | NULL                             | NULL    | NULL                          | 10278 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2) |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------+
```

The index on `emails` is, then, not being used. This index is used successfully when I join `emails` only to `departments` or only to `employees`, but not with both at once.

Why is this? What can I do about this? Is there a more efficient way to query the desired data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to do the aggregation first before the joins:

```
SELECT d.*, e.employees_count, em.emails_count
FROM d LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT e.department_id, count(*) as employees_count
      FROM employees e
      WHERE e.is_employed = true
      GROUP BY e.department_id
     ) e
     ON e.department_id = d.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT department_id, count(distinct id) as emails_count
      FROM (SELECT em.emailable_id as department_id, em.id
            FROM emails em
            WHERE em.emailable_type = 'department'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT e.department_id, em.id
            FROM emails em JOIN
                 employees e
                 ON em.emailable_id = e.id AND em.emailable_type = 'employee'
           ) ee
      GROUP BY department_id
     ) em
     ON em.department_id = d.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
ORDER BY emails_count DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

You also want an index on `emails(emailable_id, emailable_type, id)` and on `emails(emailable_type, emailable_id, id)`.

Comment: This works much faster. What's the benefit of those particular indexes? As I understand, the first would be used in the second SELECT of the UNION ALL, while the second would be used in the first SELECT of the UNION ALL. Could the second index then be replaced with just an index on `emailable_type`? I'm just trying to better understand.

Comment: @eirikir . . . The first index is optimized for the second subquery.  The first is a covering index for the first.  Replacing the index with one on `emailable_type` would work almost as well.